# Error using MakeLowercase in section heading with hyperref package

Tags: sectioning, errors, hyperref

I seem to be experiencing trouble using `\MakeLowercase` in a section heading when using the package `hyperref`. I've arrived at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{\MakeLowercase{A}}
Blah
\end{document}
```

Attempting to compile this code produces an error. The code compiles if either  `\section{\MakeLowercase{A}}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` is commented out.

I would still like to use `\MakeLowercase` in a section heading, as well as use `\hyperref` elsewhere in my document. Is there any way to remedy the situation?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\MakeLowercase` is not expandable and not allowed in `PDF` content such as bookmarks

Comment: You can use `\texorpdfstring{\MakeLowercase{A}}{a}`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Sorry for the duplication - I looked around but somehow missed the question you linked to.